# JQuery UI sortables display sort order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I cannot find in the JQUI documentation how to display the sort order.  What I want to do is display the sort order i.e. 1,2,3, 4, etc as a visual reference for a user.  The sort order obviously updates on a sort, just not sure how to find/get the sort order  - Oh I'm not sorting `<li>`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can do it youself, just recalculate order on each stop event of sortable element:

```
... 
 stop: function (event, ui) {
                setOrder();
            },
...
function setOrder() {
 $("#liContainerId").each(function (index,li) {
  // set display order here
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toArray` method of sortables:
https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

Assuming `this` is your sortable, you can use the following code to retrieve an array of DOM IDs of the sortable's items in sort order:

```
var arrayOfIds = $(this).sortable("toArray")
```

Use it in the Stop event handler to update a display, like Andrew suggested.
Check the linked documentation if you want to retrieve another attribute rather than the ID.